# Get plist into array

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, plist

I have seen lots of similar questions but nothing is working for me. I need to get the contents of my plist into an NSMutableArray.

My plist is a dictionary containing 1 array. This array has multiple dictionaries. I have used the same code in another app and it worked:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TeamsData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] retain];
NSLog(@"TEMP: %@", temp);
data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[temp objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Teams"]];
```

temp returns NULL but I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

---

**Update**

I actually discovered why my code was working in one app and not the other. In the app it did work in when I opened the plist as source the entire plist was enclosed in an array. This didn't show up when I viewed it in the standard xcode plist editor though.  So to get the same code working on the new plist I could just open it as source and enclose it in array tags.

Comment: Qn. Is there difference between this plist and the original one? Post the plist you're trying to parse for us to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you have a plist which is a dictionary containing an array of dictionaries, but you try to read the file from the bundle as if it were an array. Try using `NSDictionary`'s `-initWithContentsOfFile:` instead.

The array should have a key in the plist's dictionary, something like the folllowing:

```
...
<dict>
    <key>Teams</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            ...
        </dict>
        ...
    </array>
</dict>
```

So extracting the array should be a matter of asking the plist dictionary for the object with key `Teams`:

```
teamsArray = [ plistDictionary objectForKey: @"Teams" ];
```

Comment: That seems to work. But how do I then extract the array from the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Take it easy :)

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"menuConfig" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* amountData =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *teamsArray=[amountData objectForKey: @"InfoArrays" ];
for(amountData in teamsArray) 
{
    NSMutableArray *title = [amountData objectForKey:@"Exercesis"];
    for(amountData in title)
    {
        NSMutableArray *ExercisesDetails = [amountData objectForKey:@"ExercisesDetails"];
        for(amountData in ExercisesDetails)
        {
            NSString *exerciseDetail=[amountData objectForKey:@"exerciseDetail"];
            NSLog(@"%@",exerciseDetail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure that "take it easy" is a sufficient explanation.